# sms via salesforce mobileconnect api not sending message

Tags: mobileconnect

I'm trying to send an SMS via the following API

```
https://www.exacttargetapis.com/sms/v1/messageContact/XXXXX/send
```

The response gives a token and from that token i can see the status.
The status shows the following

```
{
  "message": "This is a test SMS this is a test SMS",
  "count": 0,
  "excludedCount": 1,
  "createDate": "2015-12-10T18:09:22.597",
  "completeDate": "2015-12-10T18:10:34.377",
  "status": "Finished",
  "tracking": []
}
```

Of particular note is  exludedcount =1 and no tracking information

How do i find out why it has excluded the sms message?

Comment: {  "mobileNumbers": ["614XXXXXXX"]} is the body that i am posting to the api ( with a real phone number )

Comment: Hi @Anton did you ever find the answer to this?  I'm having exactly the same issue!

Comment: Guess who is having the same issue? Did you manage to find the answer, @AlexMcDonald and @Anton?

Comment: @Anton Did you find a solution? I'm facing same issue...

Comment: @AlexMcDonald Did you find any solution? Why you are receiving this message?